# Efficient way to rotate strings through slicing

Tags: python, string, performance, slice

The following program is designed to take a string, `my_string = "Stackoverflow"`, and rotate it to the right based off a given integer `num`.

```
def rotateString(n, arr):
    rotate_beginning = arr[0 : len(arr)-n] 
    rotate_end = arr[len(arr)-n : ]
    newStr = rotate_end + rotate_beginning
    print (newStr)


my_string = "Stackoverflow"
num = 2
rotate(num, my_string)


# prints "owStackoverfl"
```

Is this the most efficient way to perform this function? Space complexity wise I know its not favorable to create new variables. Can it be done without creating new variables without sacrificing readability? In place?

Comment: `arr[-n:] + arr[:-n]` would be more pythonic and somewhat more efficient, too.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a comparison of suggested answers using Ipython `timeit` module:

```
from collections import deque

def rotateString1(n, arr):
    rotate_beginning = arr[0 : len(arr)-n] 
    rotate_end = arr[len(arr)-n : ]
    newStr = rotate_end + rotate_beginning
    return newStr


def rotateString2(n, arr):    
    d = deque(arr)
    d.rotate(n)
    return ''.join(d)

def rotateString3(n, arr):   
    return arr[-n:]+arr[:-n]

my_string = "Stackoverflow"
num = 2
```

Now Test using ipython:

```
%timeit rotateString1(num, my_string)
%timeit rotateString2(num, my_string)
%timeit rotateString3(num, my_string)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
465 ns ± 11.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
968 ns ± 26.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
353 ns ± 3.38 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is using `collections.deque`

```
from collections import deque

my_string = "Stackoverflow"

d = deque(my_string)
d.rotate(1)
print (''.join(d))
#wStackoverflo
```

Comment: Is this _really_ more efficient than the original solution?

Answer (score 0):

Python strings are immutable, so no you cannot do it without creating a new variable.  If you really want to be space efficient, you could use a list of characters or if you want to be very efficient, a [byte array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

```
def rotateString(n, arr):
   print (arr[len(arr)-n : ]+  arr[0 : len(arr)-n] )

rotateString(2, "Stackoverflow")
```